# If $H$ is a direct factor of $K$ and $K$ is a direct factor of $G$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: group-theory

> A normal subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be a direct factor if there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G\cong H\times K$. If $H$ is a direct factor of $K$ and $K$ is a direct factor of $G$, then prove $H$ is normal in $G$.

By definition, we have $K\cong H\times K_1$ and $G\cong K\times K_2\cong H\times K_1\times K_2$. It's easy to check that $H\times\{1\}\times\{1\}\trianglelefteq H\times K_1\times K_2$ and $H\cong H\times\{1\}\times\{1\}$. But how to prove that $H\trianglelefteq G$?

Comment: How to prove it? Take any $a = (h_1,e,e) \in H$ and any $b = (h_1,k_1,k_2) \in G$ and compute $bab^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $G\cong H×(K_1×K_2)$, it follows that $H\trianglelefteq G$.  This is a property of the [direct product of groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Definition).

Comment: It is perhaps worthwhile to stress that $\;H\times(K_1\times K_2)\cong H\times K_1\times K_2\;$ in a rather boring way.